# is possible to left join explain statement in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I would like left join an explain statement like this. Actually a need to retrieve the datatype of column and column is stored in another table named 'wyspesific' .

```
select 
st.segnam as Segment,
st.typnam as 'Sub-Segment',
group_concat(distinct ws.fldnam) as 'Field Tag Name (database)', 
group_concat(distinct ws.fldcap) as 'Field Name Label',
concat('(', group_concat(distinct of.optcap order by of.optcap desc ),')' ) as optionFieldLabel,
concat('(', group_concat(distinct of.optval order by of.optcap desc ),')' ) as optionFieldValue,
ws.isopt as isOptionField
from shiptype st
left join wyspecific ws on ws.wytypid = st.wytypid and ws.enabled = 'Y'
left join optionfields of on of.fldnam = ws.fldnam and of.deleted = 'N'
left join ( explain shipspecific ) as v on ws.fldnam = v.Field
where st.segid in(6,4,8,9,10,11,12 ) and ws.enabled = 'Y'
group by ws.fldid
order by st.segid
```

Any suggestion or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pull this information from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) instead:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='shipspecific' AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
```